# How to change an array inside an array of object in my reducer using Ramda?

Tags: arrays, updates, ramda.js, reducers

I have an object in my state like :

[image]

I have a property `sections`, that is an array of objects, I want to add an item in the `geometri_linestring` array of a specific object in the `sections` array, to do this, I did this in my reducer :

```
const setPointSuccess = curry(({ point }, state) => {
  const activeTronconId = point.activeTroncon;
  let circuit = state.addedCircuit;
  let sections = circuit.sections;
  let troncon = sections.filter(section => section.tronconId === activeTronconId)[0];
  let disabledTroncons = sections.filter(section => section.tronconId !== activeTronconId);
  const { latitude, longitude } = point;
  let geoLineString = troncon.geometri_linestring;
  geoLineString.push({ latitude, longitude });

  troncon.geometri_linestring = geoLineString;
  disabledTroncons.push(troncon);
  sections = disabledTroncons;
  circuit.sections = sections;
  let addedCircuit = circuit;

  return {
    ...state,
    addedCircuit,
  };
});
```

So, I think it is not a good code, it can be better, using ramda expressions, but I can't think of doing this, since I went so deep in that object.

Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether you are asking about redux reducers, in which case I'd suggest you to avoid methods such as `push` as they mutate the given input...

Also,
Ramda and fp in general promote an immutable approach to data transformations...

__
The following should help you do what you need,
of course you'd need to find the section (index) you need to operate on.

```js
const addCoordinates = (section, coords, state) => R.over(
  R.lensPath(['sections', section, 'geometry_linestring']),
  R.append(coords),
  state,
);

// ====

const state = {
  sections: [
    {
      geometry_linestring: [
        { longitude: 10, latitude: 20 },
        { longitude: 50, latitude: -320 },
      ],
    }
  ],
};


console.log(
  addCoordinates(0, { message: 'Hello World' }, state),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-P+CxnI2T1ohL0L2CCoq/FZmfTms2+pOw5xxeYghPovQAmBDdQb6E7Yk74lB/v84c046R1fM2ecfAhFsPzleAag==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```